# VMWare ESXi: Mark Datastore device as Flash Disk

Tags: vmware-esxi, datastore

I just found out about this feature and many of my datastores are currently marked as HDD, even though they go to flash storage backends.
If I try to makr them as flash storage, the VCSA complains there's already a filesystem on them.
Is there a way to change this without having to destroy my data?

Also, I noticed I have to do this per datastore on each host. Meaning, if I have 10 datastortes and 10 hosts, I would have to set this on 40 datastores in total?

Comment: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc/GUID-99BB81AC-5342-45E5-BF67-8D43647FAD31.html